# NodeJS - Promise.each error I couldn't debug

Tags: node.js, promise

Using Bluebird, I've been trying to make operations on an array by Promise.each sequentially but I couldn't. Indeed, it says the following : 
[ERROR_DESCRIPTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQEnR.png)

Here is the code :

```js
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Promise = require('bluebird');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  let test = [1, 2, 3];
  Promise.each(test).then((values,index) => {
      console.log(values);

      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.send(JSON.stringify("okok"));

    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you need to use `Promise.each` and you should include `res.send` outside the `promise.each` as it execute more than once, you will be end up sending res multiple times.

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Promise = require('bluebird');

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

  let test = [1, 2, 3];
  Promise.each(test,(values) => {
    console.log(values);
  });
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(JSON.stringify("okok"));

});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Oh yeah that's actually obvious. Thanks for the fast answer